# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING when passing boolean value in JSTL

Tags: java, spring, jstl, modelattribute

I'm trying to display an html label based on the value of a boolean field. The value is passed to the view from the Spring controller using `modelAttribute`.

The code snippet is below :

```
  <div>
    <span class="main-text">Vat</span>:
       <span class="sub-text">
           <c:if test="${businessOrder.isVat ne null}">
              <span class="label label-medium ${businessOrder.isVat ? 'label-success' : 'label-danger'}">
                 ${businessOrder.isVat ? 'True' : 'False'}
               </span>
           </c:if>
    </span>
  </div>
```

When I'm passing this I'm getting the above error and the page is not loading correctly. But the value is passed correctly in businessOrder attribute as a boolean value. What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
  <div>
    <span class="main-text">Vat</span>
       <span class="sub-text">
           <c:if test="${businessOrder.isVat ne null}">
              <c:choose>
                  <c:when test="${businessOrder.isVat == true}"><span class="label label-medium label-success">'True'</span></c:when>
                  <c:otherwise><span class="label label-medium label-danger">'False'</span></c:otherwise>
              </c:choose>
           </c:if>
      </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've missed a span element. I've edited my answer